# Find the centralizer of (1 2) in S5.(Conjugation)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the centralizer of (1 2) in S5. (Conjugation in the symmetric group)
I have no idea how to solve this kind of problem.
Can you show me the method? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for permutations $\sigma\in S_5$, such that
$\sigma \circ (1\ 2)\circ \sigma^{-1}= (1\ 2)$.
Carrying out function composition  you can see that LHS is another transposition, namely the one swapping $\sigma(1)$ with $\sigma(2)$. Now try to find out those for which it is the same as swapping 1 with 2.

Comment: It would be the elements that do not contain (1) or (2) in their cycles + the identity element. Correct?